# Capture desktop exclude (under) my active window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, capture

There are many questions about capture an active window or desktop include active window but my question is different:

I want capture desktop exactly under my WPF Window. I created a sample project base on the following code:

```
using (var screenBmp = new Bitmap((int)elementSize.Width,(int)elementSize.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
{
    using (var bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenBmp))
    {
        bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen((int) TopLeftPoint.X, (int)TopLeftPoint.Y, 0, 0, screenBmp.Size);

        return  Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                        screenBmp.GetHbitmap(),
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        Int32Rect.Empty,
                        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
}
```

It can capture desktop where my element is by `CopyFromScreen` but the result is a picture of my element *BUT* i want capture desktop just under my element, not include the element in my window.

Note: My element (for example a rectangle) background is Semi-Transparent or None-Transparent (has image or a solid color).

The above code result is like the below picture (the part inside Red border).
[image]

**Note:** The tree is my desktop background picture & a part of another application is visible in the image. My Window is over them.

You can see it is include my rectangle (element) and other controls over it *BUT* i want capture desktop just under my element, exclude itself and the visual of other elements over it.

---

Now my question is how can i capture desktop just under my element in a WPF window, in 2 mode such that the result be like the below pictures? :

- **A)** Include all things (windows &...) under my window, like this:

[image]

- **B)** Exclude all other things (exclude all open windows &...) under my window. Just desktop background and icons (if my window is over icons). like this:

[image]

Do you know any special Library or API to capture desktop in the above levels?

*Note: My working platform is WPF + .Net 4.5*

Comment: This is, in general, not possible.

Comment: @IInspectable, I found some APIs such as `Magnification API Overview`, but I'm not sure it can capture the image of under my elements: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692402%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: The Magnification API magnifies what's visible. It cannot be used to uncover the area obscured by windows.

Comment: A is certainly possible but not B.

Comment: @MarkFeldman: A is not possible, without first hiding the window, taking a snapshot and showing the window again. There is no conceptual difference between looking behind your window, or anyone else's. It's just not supported.

Comment: Oh ok, I misread the question and thought A had to include his own window. Yeah, forget it. What's this for anyway? I can only think of nefarious applications.

Comment: @MarkFeldman, i want blend my UI with desktop space and make some nice effects... It is more creative than what you think!

Comment: In that case I'd recommend having a look into [shader effects](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71617/Getting-Started-with-Shader-Effects-in-WPF).

Comment: @MarkFeldman, my real program use `shader effects` too and i want doing some works by it and i need desktop capture...